# MySQL equivalent of a spatial ST_Union aggregate function?

Tags: mysql, aggregate, mysql-5.7, spatial, geometry

I'm working on a DB-spacial project in Mysql and I was trying to perform a union operation for a group of shapes. Im looking for something similar to the  SQL Server function [`UnionAggregate`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/spatial-geometry/unionaggregate-geometry-data-type?view=sql-server-2017), or the PostGIS Spatial Aggregate function [`ST_Union`](http://www.postgis.net/docs/ST_Union.html)

for example (In SQL SERVER):

```
SELECT
        geometry::STGeomFromWKB(Shape,27582),
        area_code
FROM area_table 
WHERE area_code='xxxxxxx';
```

ST_GeomFromWKB do the same job in Mysql.

[image]

in the second part and with the `UnionAggregate` function + group by :

```
select 
        dbo.UnionAggregate((geometry::STGeomFromWKB(Shape,27582)).MakeValid()),
        area_code
FROM area_table 
WHERE area_code='xxxxxxx'
GROUP BY area_code;
```

[image]

How to perform a similar operation (aggregate+group by) in MySQL?

Comment: What does UnionAggregate do?

Comment: Performs a union operation on a set of geography objects. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff929095.aspx

Comment: Perhaps: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/gis-class-multipolygon.html

Comment: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-union

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found another alternative to perform the union aggregation by using [ST_Union](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html#function_st-union). I had some issues cause this Mysql function get only 2 parameters as inputs.

As a solution, I create my own function as follow :

```
CREATE FUNCTION `fct_create_geom_collection`(ac CHAR(8))          
 RETURNS GEOMETRY
BEGIN
                    DECLARE position INT;
                    DECLARE sortie BOOLEAN DEFAULT FALSE;
                    -- get all area_IDs
                    DECLARE curgeom CURSOR FOR
                    SELECT DISTINCT area_ID     
                    FROM area_table  
                    WHERE area_code= ac ORDER BY area_ID;
                    DECLARE CONTINUE HANDLER FOR NOT FOUND SET sortie = TRUE; 

    OPEN curgeom;   
                  -- get the first area_id
                   FETCH curgeom INTO position ;
                  -- put the shape into @var_g_0 for this area_id
                   SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(Shape,27582) INTO @var_g_0 
                   FROM area_table  
                   WHERE area_ID = position  ;              
    LLD: LOOP
    IF sortie THEN
    LEAVE LLD;
    END IF;
                    -- get the second area_id
                    FETCH curgeom INTO position  ;
                    -- put the second  shape into @var_g for this area_id
                    SELECT ST_GeomFromWKB(Shape,27582) INTO @var_g 
                    FROM area_table  
                    WHERE area_ID    = position   ;

                    -- performing a union operation between @var_g_0 and @var_g
                    SET @geom = ST_UNION(@var_g_0,@var_g); -- enclosed st_union                 
                    -- put the result into @var_g_0
                    SET @var_g_0 = @geom;   

                   END LOOP;
                   CLOSE curgeom;
                   RETURN ST_GeomFromText(ST_ASTEXT(@geom)); 
                 -- RETURN ST_GeomFromWKB(@geom); 

END$$
```

This function enable an aggregate union over shapes for each "area code" which is what UnionAggregate do and what I need.