# Use GROUP_CONCAT() to generate polygons in mysql

Tags: mysql, aggregate, spatial, group-concatenation

I have a table that has columns `zone`(name of the zone which is a string), `longitude` (decimal), `latitude` (decimal), `logical order` (integer).

`logical_order` indicates the order in which the coordinates can be combined to create the polygon. For example, each zone will have multiple rows in this table with different `longitude`, `latitude`. For each zone row, the `logical_order` will start at 1 (for starting point) and increase by one per row. For example, if a zone has 3 points, `logical_order` will run from 1 through 3. Coordinates at 3 are not the same as at 1. In other words, the coordinates do not close the polygon.

I'm trying to create `POLYGON` by grouping coordinates of each zone and using spatial package as below:

I tried the below query:

```
SELECT t0.zone, ST_GeometryFromText(CONCAT("POLYGON(", GROUP_CONCAT(t0.coordinate ORDER BY t0.logical_order SEPARATOR ','), ")")) FROM
(
    SELECT zone, CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, logical_order FROM zones
    UNION
    SELECT zone, CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, COUNT(zone) + 1 AS logical_order FROM zones GROUP BY zone
) t0 
GROUP BY t0.zone
```

However, this gives me the error:

```
Error Code: 3037. Invalid GIS data provided to function st_geometryfromtext.
```

How can I fix this error? Am I approaching the right way?

EDIT:

If I try without the `ST_GeometryFromText()` in the second query, I get a string like:

```
POLYGON(77.5068350000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -11.4907909800)
```

After adding two parenthesis like below still give the same error:

```
POLYGON((77.5068350000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -11.4907909800,179.7363280000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -60.0000000000,77.5068350000 -11.4907909800))
```

EDIT:

SQL fiddle with sample data: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!9/5094e5/5

Comment: Can you check that all polygons have the last point the same as the first point (ie they close the cycle)? The `GROUP BY` you use to produce this doesn't look very sound.

Comment: @ypercubeᵀᴹ You are right, they don't. I think it's due to limit in size allowed for `group_concat()` because at that step, it doesn't contain all the coordinates. I also revised the `group by` to a `where` clause. The union gives the correct result but the `group_concat()` does not.

Comment: Side note:  `DECIMAL(8,6)/(9,6)` is precise enough to distinguish people standing next each other; having 10 decimal places is excessive.

Comment: What version of MySQL?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [MySQL equivalent of a spatial ST\_Union aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/165606/mysql-equivalent-of-a-spatial-st-union-aggregate-function)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is likely cause because the "cycle" isn't closed, i.e. last point in the polygon does not match the first one.

This can be from two issues:

- the [`group_concat_max_len`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/server-system-variables.html#sysvar_group_concat_max_len) setting is too low (default is 1024).

Solution: increase it, either in the server or session level.

- the error-prone `GROUP BY` used to add the additional point.

The `GROUP BY` you use is prone to give wrong results, as it may not always select the row you want (`WHERE logical_order = 1`) to read the coordinates:

```
(
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 
           logical_order 
    FROM zones
    UNION
    -- This is to close the polygon by adding the first coordinate also 
    -- as the final coordinate of the zone. 
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 
           COUNT(zone) + 1 AS logical_order 
    FROM zones 
    GROUP BY zone
) t0
```

I'd write it like this:

```
(
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude) AS coordinate, 
           logical_order 
    FROM zones
    UNION ALL
    -- This is to close the polygon by adding the first coordinate also
    -- as the final coordinate of the zone. 
    SELECT zone, 
           CONCAT(longitude, ' ', latitude), 
           1000000     -- unlikely to have a million points polygon
    FROM zones
    WHERE logical_order = 1
) t0
```

Comment: The problem was I was using double quotes in `concat` instead of single quotes eh. Thank you for the effort and working through this. You are awesome :)

Comment: I don't think single vs double makes a difference (except perhaps your server has non-default settings). It's good to always use single quotes for string literals.

Answer (score 2):

What you want is a [Spatial Aggregate](https://postgis.net/docs/manual-1.5/ch08.html#PostGIS_Aggregate_Functions). Unfortunately, MySQL doesn't yet support them, consider upgrading to PostgreSQL and PostGIS (which is in every way better).

That said, **there is a better workaround**. You can find that here,

- [MySQL equivalent of a spatial `ST_Union` aggregate function?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/q/165606/2639)